# cant install h5py on a nano jetson

Tags: python, h5py, nvidia-jetson-nano

when i try pip3 install h5py on the ubuntu 18.04 from nvidia for the nano jetson i get this error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/mimus/virtualenv/venv/bin/python3 /home/mimus/virtualenv/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-sr8cr1rz/normal --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version == "3.7"' 'numpy==1.17.5; python_version == "3.8"' pkgconfig 'Cython>=0.29.14; python_version >= "3.8"' 'numpy==1.12; python_version == "3.6"' 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version >= "3.9"' 'Cython>=0.29; python_version < "3.8"' Check the logs for full command output.
```

i have already installed cython numpy and six but im having the same problem, hope you can help me

Comment: Which versions of those packages do you have installed?
Check with `pip show`.

Answer (score 0):

I got h5py to install on the Jetson Nano by downgrading it to version 2.10.0 instead of the default 3.x.x.